# How to set rowspan in itext using do while loop in android studio

Tags: java, android, itext

My datas in PDF consists of 20 rows. I'm using do while loop for getting this 20 values from database. I trying to set rowspan for the last set of datas, which am unable to do so, as the last values are getting broken. Below is my codings...

```
PdfPTable tablel = new PdfPTable(3);
tablel.setWidthPercentage(100);

//Header
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("S No"));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Parameter"));
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unit"));

tablel.addCell(cell1);
tablel.addCell(cell2);
tablel.addCell(cell3);

//Datas
Cursor c= dbs.query("kiosk_trn_tsoilparameter", new String[]{"soilparam_gid","soilparam_soil_gid","soil_parameter","soil_uom","soil_results"
                }, "soilparam_soil_gid" + "=? COLLATE NOCASE",
                new String[]{id}, null, null, null, null);
                
                int i = 1;
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                //to get increment values of i
                String group = String.valueOf(i);
                cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(group));
                tablel.addCell(cell1);
                
                String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM core_mst_tmaster....";
                Cursor cursor1 = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);              
                if(cursor1.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String machine = cursor1.getString(0);
                        cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        tablel.addCell(cell1);
                    }
                    
                    String selectQuery2 = "SELECT  * FROM core_mst_tmaster ....";
                Cursor cursor2 = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery3, null);              
                if(cursor2.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String machine = cursor2.getString(0);
                        cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        tablel.addCell(cell2);
                    }
                    String selectQuery3 = "SELECT  * FROM core_mst_tmaster.... ";
                Cursor cursor3 = dbs.rawQuery(selectQuery3, null);              
                if(cursor3.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String machine = cursor3.getString(0);
                        cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        cell3.setRowspan(3);
                        tablel.addCell(cell3);
                    }
                i++;
                while (c.moveToNext());
                }
                document.add(tablel);
```

I have also tried to put if loop to get first set of values and for the remaining set of values I assigned empty values and tried to assigned rowspan for the remaining set of values, but still it is not working.

Below is the coding...

````
//to get first set of values
if(i==1){
                    String machine = cursor3.getString(0);
                        cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));                        
                        tablel.addCell(cell3);
                }else{
// to get remaining values
                    String machine = cursor3.getString(0);
                        cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(machine));
                        cell3.setRowspan(3);
                        tablel.addCell(cell3);
                }

```
Any codings I missed out...please help me out...
````

Comment: Tag [android-studio] is for questions about using Android Studio. Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general.

Comment: add the sample pdf layout you are expecting and what actually came of your code also for better understanding

Comment: I solved it..by creating 2 separate 2 tables and joined it. First I created the first table which contains 4 rows and then I created another table which contains 1 row, which I need to set row span.  Then I joined there 2 tables. I referred this link , which is very useful to me. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654191/how-to-show-two-pdftables-next-to-each-other-in-itext)